# Does virtual cohomological dimension tell us anything about vanishing?

Tags: homological-algebra, group-actions, group-cohomology

Given a discrete torsion-free group $G$, we define the cohomological dimension ($cd$) of $G$ to be the minimum $N$ such that $H^{n}(G,M)=0$ for all $\mathbb{Z}G$-modules $M$ and all $n>N$. This is extended to groups with torsion as virtual cohomological dimension ($vcd$): the virtual cohomological dimension of $G$ is the cohomological dimension of a torsion-free subgroup of finite index (that this is well defined is not immediately obvious, but true). While it is interesting that this is a well defined invariant, does this contain any more information?

For example, if $G$ has $vcd(G)=1$, does this tell us that $H^{2}(G,M)$ vanishes for all $\mathbb{Q}G$-modules, or something similar? In the case of $G$ a cocompact lattice in $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$, then we can establish this by computation of the cohomology of the associated orbifold quotient (see for example Harder's *Cohomology of Arithmetic Groups*) but this approach is not available in general. Can we say anything meaningful about group cohomology knowing virtual cohomological dimension in general?

Comment: For a $\mathbb{Q}[G]$-module $M$ with virtual codimension $1$, and $H \leq G$ torsion-free of finite index, wouldn’t you have an injective restriction map $H^2(G,M) \rightarrow H^2(H,M)=0$, hence the cohomology vanishing that you suggested? In general, that would tell you that $[G:H]\cdot H^n(G,M)=0$ if $H \leq G$ is torsion free of finite index…

Comment: @Aphelli That woud be a very simple solution - thank you. I'm not seeing why the restriction map would be injective though. Could you say a few words about why that would be the case?

Comment: Ah, I see. This comes from the composition of the restriction and corestriction maps. That works perfectly, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am turning my comment into an answer.

Let $G$ have virtual cohomological dimension $N$. Let $M$ be a $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module and $n > N$. Let $H \leq G$ be a torsion-free subgroup of finite index and cohomological dimension $n$.

Then the sequence $H^n(G,M) \rightarrow H^n(H,M) \rightarrow H^n(G,M)$ (restriction then corestriction) is formally $[G:H]$.

But our assumptions imply that $H^n(H,M)=0$: therefore $[G:H] \cdot H^n(G,M)=0$. In particular, if $M$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, then $H^n(G,M)=0$.